# Fast way to import 2GB csv file into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import, csv

I am new to database,I am using SSMS 2008 R2 to import 2GB of data from a `.csv` file.

It is taking around 115mins to import.

Can anybody let me know any better way to perform this import.

Comment: You should show the definition of the table(s) involved, how the data is clustered, how many indexes it has, ... and some indication of the hardware on which the database it's running, to help assess whether 115 mins is considered *normal* or *not*.

Comment: Not only that.... _what code are you using to import it_? As far as we can tell you're just typing it in manually.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [bcp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) or [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services). Read [Import and Export Bulk Data by Using the bcp Utility (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-and-export-bulk-data-by-using-the-bcp-utility-sql-server) and [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx). Also, read [How to Analyze SQL Server Performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) to be able to tell *why* something is slow.

*After* you've read those, come back with a more actionable question, including structure of table, csv structure, repeatability of the job, access issues etc.